# Saxon transformation failure - which line is at fault?

Tags: saxon

I am using Saxon to transform an XML file to XHTML. I am calling Saxon as a command-line instance through a Perl script.

I am getting the following error:

Validation error 
  FORG0001: Invalid date "-" (No year after '-')
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported

This error is caused by a non-date passed to an XSLT function that I have written that expects a date. However, I am using this function in many places in my XSLT file and I do not know which instance is causing the problem. I can troubleshoot manually but is it possible to have this transform error also point out what line in the XSLT is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you didn't get an answer to this question. Do feel free to use Saxonica's help lists and support forums, in which case we will always try to help; it's hit-and-miss whether a question on StackOverflow gets noticed.

Recent releases of Saxon produce an XSLT stack trace which shows the function/template calling stack at the point where a run-time error occurs. It's not clear why you aren't seeing this; it might be something to do with the Perl script.

Another diagnostic technique is to use the -T option to produce a full execution trace; the final lines of the trace will tell you what code was being executed at the point of failure.